# Laravel 5 missing required parameters on destroy route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I recently upgraded from laravel 5.1 to 5.2 and now I'm getting an error of `Missing required parameters for [Route: example.destroy] [URI: example/{args}]`.

The error occurs here:
`<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo route('example.destroy'); ?>" method="post">` on the action attribute of the form.

Here's how the route was registered on the `route.php`

```
Route::resource('example', 'ExampleController');
```

When I was in 5.1, there was no error with this line. Just went I upgrade to 5.2, it now occurs.

The functionality of this is that it will allow user to delete multiple entries by checking the checkboxes that they wish to be deleted. Then upon submit, it will redirect to the destroy method on the controller.

Comment: Please post the route definition for the route with the name `example.destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo       
url('example'); ?>" method="post">

Route::post('example', 'ExampleController@destroy');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when updating my app to Laravel 5.2.

Apparently, Laravel 5.2 require a valid Route to "destroy resource", ex:

```
/my-route/item-to-destroy/{id}
```

Here, in our apps I'm putting an "{id} = 0" or "{id} = null", at the end of each route (when calling a "route destroy" that is not yet ready).

In your case, it would be similar to that:

```
<form action="<?php echo route('example_route.destroy', ['id'=>0]); ?>" method="post">
```

or, declare a valid resource id:

```
<form action="<?php echo route('example_route.destroy', ['id'=>$object->id]); ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: Yeah, same here though I just set it to blank. `<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo route('example.destroy', ''); ?>" method="post">` But is this the right thing to do?

Comment: Is not entirely correct, depending how your application works, it can lead to gaps in access to routes. But, it works :D

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo route('example.destroy', $record->id); ?>" method="post">
```

or Laravel way:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['example.destroy', $record->id],
                                                'method' => 'delete']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: This is applicable when you have a page that does a one-is-to-one delete. However in my case, I am doing a multiple delete on a single page.